# How to close aside with same hotkey?

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I use [this hotkey](http://jsfiddle.net/firehist/nzUBg/) code for shortcut in my website ,now how can i use that same hotkey to close the block?

My block is a AngularStrap aside,
I use 3 aside in my page,top,bottom and right
I use that code like below , use F1 to open aside , now how can i use same key to close aside

```js
keyboardManager.bind('f1', function() {
       $aside({scope: $scope, template: 'aside/passenger.tpl.html',show:true});
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly how you have set up your code, but I would do something like this:

```
var shown = false;

keyboardManager.bind('f1', function() {
    $aside({scope: $scope, template: 'aside/passenger.tpl.html',show: !shown});
});
```

The idea is, that instead of specifying that "show" should be true, you inverse the value of show each time you press "f1". This way you can reuse your bound hotkey, by reverse what it dies every time you use it.